# How to create an animated GIF from JPEGs on Java Google App Engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine, animated-gif

I am trying to get animated GIF from jpeg's on App Engine. I can create such GIF in an ordinary Java environment using this class [GifSequenceWriter](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java) But what about GAE?

Answer (score 0):

Since use of the `java.awt.*` package is not possible on GAE, you won't be able to use `GifSequenceWriter`. However, you might be able to use the [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/?csw=1) provided by App Engine, mirroring the `GifSequenceWriter` code.

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible to mirror?